# PhpStorm update php file PhpDoc on save

Tags: phpstorm

Is it possible to update comment on file save something like:

```
<?php
    /**
     * FileController Class
     *
     * @package CMS
     * @author mydomain.com
     * @copyright 2023
     * @version 1.50: FileController.php, v1.00 5/10/2023 11:05 AM
     * @updated 5/22/2023 12:05 AM
     *
     */
```

Once file is saved `@update` tag is updated with current time/date.

I tried using live template, micros, but nothing works.

Comment: Should be possible, yes. You just need the **Copyright plugin** (comes bundled with the IDE) and use `$file.lastModified` variable there. Make sure it is used to make changes on Save. Have a look. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/copyright.html Not sure how it will work if your copyright comment has different structure/content for different files though (as I have never used this plugin myself)

Comment: Another option: make an external script (batch/shell .. or in PHP/JS -- that will parse the file and do such change) and call it as a File Watcher. I'm just not sure if it will not cause any issues .. since it will be trying to modify the file itself (there is a chance to see file content conflict/file was modified outside popup). Worth checking out anyway.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, I have tried copyright plugin as well, but no luck.